# MS Teams Toolkit doesn't build app package zip correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, microsoft-teams

as a long time reader of stackoverflow articles, I now have a problem myself to which I have not yet found an answer.
I am trying to build a tabs app for MS Teams. In VS Code a first version is already running as desired. The debug version runs in the browser, all good. But as soon as I try to build an app package, the compiler runs through, but except for the manifest file and two icons, the ZIP archive is empty.
This is despite the fact that the build process runs cleanly. I see all the generated files in VS Code. But all the packing together in the app package somehow doesn't work. Also the way via Azure is not different. Building yes, but at the end the ZIP archive is basically empty.
I have set up all the necessary accounts and subscriptions and I don't get any error messages anymore.
I strictly followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform//sbs-gs-javascript?tabs=vscode%2Cvsc%2Cviscode

Does anyone have any ideas?

File-Tree

[[image]]

Build-Dir

[[image]]

Comment: Ahh..I think I have a wrong understanding of the matter. The app seems to be on Azure and the app package archive just has the info on where it can be retrieved. That is why the manifest and the images.
Am I seeing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its getting correctly.

A Teams app package consists of three files:

- The manifest.json.
- A color icon for your app to display in the public or organization
  app catalog.
- An outline icon for display on the Teams activity bar.

Reference Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/visual-studio-code-overview#configure-your-app

Comment: Thanks! With that understanding it works fine.